# wpf use ellipse for progress

Tags: wpf, progress, ellipse

curious about using ellipse for showing progress, probably as the progress bar uses IsIndeterminate. I'll have ellipse where either color or opacity create an effect of moving
from left to right, but instead of a sold bar, ellipse controls spread apart. I'm not looking
for a working example, just hoping for some direction in the best way to pursue this.

```
<Canvas VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="canvas1" >
    <Ellipse Height="15" Name="ellipse1" Fill="DodgerBlue"  Stroke="DodgerBlue" Width="15" />
    <Ellipse Height="15" Name="ellipse3" Fill="DimGray"  Stroke="DodgerBlue" Width="15" Canvas.Left="21" Canvas.Top="0" />
    <Ellipse Height="15" Name="ellipse2" Fill="DimGray" Stroke="DodgerBlue" Width="15" Canvas.Left="42" Canvas.Top="0" />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably start by creating a UserControl that contains an animated ellipse that "pulses" -- becomes brighter and then fades back, waits a second, and then brightens again, and so on.

I'd put multiple instances of that control into a UniformGrid.

To get the desired effect of left-to-right, you'd want to expose some property that would be bound to the start time for the animation, so that the leftmost instance starts at 0, next slightly later, next slightly later, and so on. I'd expect to play with that timing until I get the desired left-to-right "flow".